# Select data from many tables at the same time order by date (stream)

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I want to get data from many tables with an order by created_at to make a stream.

Tables:

news, reviews, videos, games

These all tables has created_at field.

These data must be in an order with created_at.

How can i do with mysql?

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you look on the examples on the doctrine site?

Comment: There is no example like my question on the doctrine docs. This is a sql question. I will correct my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can **project union-compatible relations** from each table, this is easy.  For example, if all tables have `id` and `name` columns:

```
select id, name, created_at from news
union all select id, name, created_at from reviews
union all select id, name, created_at from videos
union all select id, name, created_at from games
order by created_at
;
```

Definitions:

- [projection (relational algebra)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29)
- [union-compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29) - the relations (tables) must have the same set of attributes (columns)

Comment: Thank you. One more question, how can i seperate them with a title? For example, i have to know which data is belong to which table. So i need to give a title to them right?

Comment: You could select a literal string, e.g. `select id, name, created_at, 'news' as table_name from news`

Comment: Not exactly. I have to know, which data belongs to which type. So i have to give all data (all rows) a type like - type: game, type: video, type:review bla bla.

Comment: Ahhh my bad. Thank you so much! Your comment is exactly what i want. My mistake!